# how to make Pagerequest with JdbcTemplate in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

i want to make a `PageRequest` in `JdbcTemplate`.What I do not want to do is to use `JPA`.I searched almost 4 hours but could not find anything usefull.Please tell me if possible, how can I do it

**Edit**
I want to reload data from `Oracle`, but do not want to use `JPARepository`
Here is my code.This is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private OrderService orderService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/reload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Order> reload(){
    return  orderService.reload();
}
```

This is my service

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

public List<Order> reload(){
    return orderRepository.reload();
}
```

This is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository {

public List<Order> reload();
}
```

This is my repositoryImpl class

```
 @Repository
 public class OrderRepositoryImpl implements OrderRepository{

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 
@Override
public List<Order> reload(){

}
```

Comment: I edited my question.Sorry for giving less information

Answer (score 0):

Using spring-data-commons

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.support.PageableExecutionUtils;
import org.springframework.data.repository.support.PageableExecutionUtils.TotalSupplier;

/**
 * @param content list from jdbcTemplate
 * @param pageNum : zero-based, if null default to zero
 * @param pageSize : if null default list size
 * @return Page object (zero-based)
 */
public static <T> Page<T> pagingList(List<T> content, Integer pageNum, Integer pageSize){
    Assert.notNull(content, "List content must not be null!");
    pageNum = (pageNum == null) ? 0 : pageNum;
    pageSize = (pageSize == null) ? content.size() : pageSize;

    PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(pageNum, pageSize);

    //System.out.println(" ======== PAGEABLE ========= ");
    //System.out.println(" pageable.getOffset     : " + pageable.getOffset());
    //System.out.println(" pageable.getPageNumber : " + pageable.getPageNumber());
    //System.out.println(" pageable.getPageSize   : " + pageable.getPageSize());

    TotalSupplier totalSupplier = new TotalSupplier() {

        @Override
        public long get() {
            return content.size();
        }
    };

    int fromOffset = pageable.getOffset();
    int toOffset =  Math.min(content.size(), fromOffset + pageSize);
    List<T> listPaging = new ArrayList<>();
    if(fromOffset < toOffset){
        listPaging = content.subList(fromOffset, toOffset);
    }
    return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(listPaging, pageable, totalSupplier);
}
```

Above code does :

- Accept list from jdbcTemplate
- Create PageRequest object (with pageNum and pageSize)
- Create subList from original list start from element fromOffset and toOffset

Be aware for huge size of list, not yet testing it.

Reference : [Github spring-data-jpa](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QuerydslJpaRepository.java#L157)